# Android layout for ListView followed by non-scrolling bar of text at bottom of screen

Tags: android, listview, layout, textview

I'm having trouble setting up an Android Layout.

What I would *like* is a scrollable ListView followed by a small bar of text (TextView) that doesn't scroll and always stays at the bottom of the screen.

it would look like this:

ListViewItem1

ListViewItem2

ListViewItem3

…

Bar of Text Here (always displayed irrespective of scroll state of the ListView)

I've tried a bunch of different variations on this, but none shows the static text

Any thoughts as to where I'm going wrong?

TKS!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ListView android:id="@+id/list2" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dip" android:text="Bar of text that always stays at the bottom of the screen" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a `RelativeLayout`. Anchor the `TextView` to the bottom using `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`. Have the `ListView` fill the remainder.

Or, use a single `LinearLayout`, setting the `ListView`'s `android:layout_height` to `0px` and `android:layout_weight` to `1`, and the `TextView` following the `ListView` as children of the `LinearLayout`.

Comment: Did you mean "android:layout_width to 1" or "android:layout_weight to 1"?

Comment: @Nemi: thanks for pointing that out -- I've fixed my original answer.

Comment: I tried the LinearLayout option with the height 0px and layout_weight 1 and didn't work. Can you please post the XML?

Comment: The relativeLayout worked but takes too much work to place all the component around.

Answer (score 1):

Use android:layout_weight to make your listview fill the remainder of the page not used by the static text.

like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ListView android:id="@+id/list2" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"/><!-- here's the important part-->
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Bar of text that always stays at the bottom of the screen" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it really sounds like you want to be using a [footer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addFooterView(android.view.View)), which ListView already has and does exactly what you describe.

Comment: Actually, addFooterView seems to ensure that you can have the added view as the last element of the list, it wouldn't help in weighting it to the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @CommonsWare answer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ListView android:id="@+id/actionsListView" 
        android:layout_height="0px" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"/>    

    <TextView android:text="" 
        android:id="@+id/progressTextLabel" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

Hope it helps:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="420dp"
        android:id="@+id/rel">
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rel"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:text="Bar of text that always stays at the bottom of the screen" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```